# How to zoom in in XQuartz without a mouse?

Tags: zooming, x11, xquartz

I tried combinations of `<cmd>`, `Alt`, `Opt` and `+`, `-` to zoom in. None works.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is related to the settings in the Mac. I can zoom in and out, ie. with two fingers on the touchpad.